# Finding if a variabile is defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to implement a module that expects as parameter some variable declarations. I have to find a way of validating those variables, so that I didn't predefined them.

Example

```
declare @var int
set @var = 1

if isdeclared(@var) == 0
begin
    declare @var int
    print @var
end
print @var
```

Comment: I think you need to give some more details about why you need to do this and how you are passing the "parameters" you mentioned. Declaring a variable twice is a compilation error, so you can't CATCH it at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server parses the code for variable declarations before it executes the code.

This code will work just fine

```
if 1 = 0
begin
    declare @var int
    print @var
end
print @var
```

The variable is declare even if the code that declares the variable is never executed.

What you might want to do is to test if the variable is assigned or not instead.

```
if 1 = 0
begin
    declare @var int
    set @var = 1
    print @var
end

if @var is null 
begin
  set @var = 2
end

print @var
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely certain what you mean by `module`, but if you create a stored procedure you can be certain of what variables exist in that scope.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure (@var1 AS INT = NULL, @var2 AS INT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @var3 INT

  IF (@var1 IS NULL)
    SET @var3 = 'Nothing was passed in for @var1'

  IF (@var1 IS NULL AND @var2 IS NULL)
    SET @var3 = @var3 + ', '

  IF (@var2 IS NULL)
    SET @var3 = @var3 + 'Nothing was passed in for @var2'

  SELECT
    @var1, @var2, @var3

END
```

Even though the parameters are optional, they're still decalred and have default values (NULL in this case).  So, you don't need to check declarations, only the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can't  `Complie` or `Run` Sql statement in `Sql Server Management Studio`.

Say, in `JS` you can compile/execute code block having a undeclared variable and can check if the variable is declare or not using `typedef` but in Sql Server it's not possible till to current version. Thanks for your time.